# Как удалить из ссылок на WP Woocommerce этот фрагмент?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Значит, на главной странице и на остальных в конце есть вот такое:

http://shop.example.com.ua**/?v=3943d8795e03**

Как такое убрать? Найти не могу.

Вот скрин этого:

http://prntscr.com/m2j6id

Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решил свою проблему. 
В Woocommerce - Найстройки - Стандартное местоположение клиента - (поставил настройку на: Геолокация вместо Геолокация с кешированием).